# How can I use S3InboundFileSynchronizer to synchronize an S3Bucket organized with directories?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-integration

I'm trying to use the S3InboundFileSynchronizer to synchronize an S3Bucket to a local directory.  The bucket is organised with sub-directories such as:

`bucket ->
            2016 ->
                       08 ->
                          daily-report-20160801.csv
                          daily-report-20160802.csv`

etc...

Using this configuration:

```
@Bean
        public S3InboundFileSynchronizer s3InboundFileSynchronizer() {
            S3InboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer = new S3InboundFileSynchronizer(amazonS3());
            synchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
            synchronizer.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
            synchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("REDACTED");
            synchronizer.setFilter(new S3RegexPatternFileListFilter(".*\\.csv$"));
            Expression expression = PARSER.parseExpression("#this.substring(#this.lastIndexOf('/')+1)");
            synchronizer.setLocalFilenameGeneratorExpression(expression);
            return synchronizer;
        }
```

I'm able to get as far as connecting to the bucket and listing its contents. When it comes time to read from the bucket the following exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory; nested exception is   
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; 
nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'path' must in pattern [BUCKET/KEY].
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:266)
```

Reviewing the code it seems that it'd be impossible to ever synchronize an S3Bucket w/ sub-directories:

```
private String[] splitPathToBucketAndKey(String path) {
    Assert.hasText(path, "'path' must not be empty String.");
    String[] bucketKey = path.split("/");
    Assert.state(bucketKey.length == 2, "'path' must in pattern [BUCKET/KEY].");
    Assert.state(bucketKey[0].length() >= 3, "S3 bucket name must be at least 3 characters long.");
    bucketKey[0] = resolveBucket(bucketKey[0]);
    return bucketKey;
}
```

Is there some configuration I'm missing or is this a bug?

(I'm assuming it's a bug 'till I'm told otherwise so I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/pull/46) with a proposed fix.)

Comment: OK. Since you even have raised an SO question I'm switching to you problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug and submitted PullRequest is good for fix.

Only the solution as a workaround is like custom `SessionFactory<S3ObjectSummary>` which returns a custom `S3Session` extension with the provided fix in the PR.